# Tweepy stops after 1500 Tweets have been collected

Tags: python, tweepy

I have set `wait_on_rate_limit` to `True`, but it stops once it reaches 1500 Tweets. I want to collect 20k Tweets, but it does not work. Here is my code:

```py
import os
import tweepy as tw

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(apikey,apisecret) #calling OAuthHandler required for authantication with Twitter
auth.set_access_token(accesstoken,accesstokensecret)

api = tw.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

for i, status in enumerate(tw.Cursor(api.search,q = search_word, lang ='de',since = date_since, count = 3000).items(3000)):
    print(i, status.text)
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help!

BTW: I am running this on Google Colab, and I am a noob with no prior experience

Comment: What version of tweepy are you using? Version 3.5 has a `1500` result limit. I don't see the same limit on version 3.10 though.

Comment: I am using 3.10 currently. Can I change that result limit somehow? What is the point of having such a limit?

Comment: This isn't reproducible. What are `search_word` and `date_since`? Are you sure there aren't only 1500 results?

Comment: I defined them this way: search_word = 'pharma -filter:retweets'  
date_since = '2019-01-01'   I think I should get more tweets than. On a non API tool called Twint I managed to get more than that.

Answer (score 0):

My attempts to reproduce this resulted in exactly 1530 Tweets, not 1500.
That is likely the total amount of Tweets that match the search within the last week.

From the documentation for the [standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) that [`API.search`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#API.search) uses:

> Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week.

It also says:

> The Search API is not a complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. The index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators

`since` is not a valid parameter for the method and endpoint, and the maximum valid `count` is 100.

The rate limit for the endpoint is 180 requests / 15-min window with user auth and 450 requests / 15-min window with app auth, which should provide 18000 and 45000 Tweets / 15 min. with `count` set to the maximum.

There isn't a ["result limit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68087056/tweepy-stops-after-1500-tweets-have-been-collected#comment120341256_68087056) of 1500 in either Tweepy v3.10 or v3.5, and like you said, [that tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68087056/tweepy-stops-after-1500-tweets-have-been-collected#comment120357595_68087056) doesn't use Twitter's API and violates Twitter's Terms of Service.

Comment: If I use the academic API which can access all historical tweets, would the 'since' parameter work? Or is there another way to use the full potential of academic APIs in Tweepy?

Comment: If you mean the Academic Research product track, that's for Twitter API v2, and the [full-archive search](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all) endpoint also does not have a `since` parameter.

Comment: So there is literally no way to get certain types of tweets from a specific time interval? I can't believe that. If that's not possible, what is the point of having access to the full archive?

Comment: If you look at the documentation for the endpoint, you'll see that there are `end_time` and `start_time` parameters. This is not relevant to your original question; if you have further questions about this, you should ask them separately.